# Unable to parse JSON when making JSONP call

Tags: json, backbone.js, jsonp

When  tried parsing the below data in client using JSONP (regular ajax call is looking good.)getting error because it is having a html content.
My server codes supports JSONP calls.

EG : JSON.parse('{"key":"`<input type="text">`"}')

Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token t

Can some one help to over come this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server doesn't escape strings when bake JSON. It should looks like:

```
{"key":"<input type=\"text\">"}
```

Comment: if so how the same is working on a regular ajax call ?

Comment: maybe values of keys in other regular ajax call don't have double quotes inside.. How do you generate JSON?